# How can I get delayed_job to log application output?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, delayed-job

I have added the following code to my initializers:

```
require 'delayed/worker'

Delayed::Worker.logger = ActiveSupport::BufferedLogger.new("log/#{Rails.env}_delayed_jobs.log", Rails.logger.level)

module Delayed
  class Worker
    def say_with_flushing(text, level = Logger::INFO)
      if logger
        say_without_flushing(text, level)
        logger.flush
      end
    end
    alias_method_chain :say, :flushing
  end
end
```

But it only seems to output stuff like:

2011-09-06T14:02:04-0700: [Worker(delayed_job host:Caribbean.local pid:80322)] 1 jobs processed at 16.5391 j/s, 0 failed ...
2011-09-06T14:03:19-0700: [Worker(delayed_job host:Caribbean.local pid:80322)] MailTest completed after 0.2072

...

Is there a way to get it to actually output what it's doing?  Ideally what I am trying to get is the actual outgoing email content that would normally be seen in development mode, but have it go into the delayed_job.log (regardless of rails environment).

So without having mailing go through delayed_job, in production mode the output in the log is something like:
[Mail sent to foo@foo.com]

But I want to get the actual contents as they'd be displayed if I were in development mode--  (the entire email body, subject, etc) but again in the delayed_job log because delayed_job is handling mailing emails.